# Failed to sell tokens (probably scam but want to make sure)

Tags: web3.py, pancakeswap, scam

I was writing a bot to monitor new liquidity pools that open up in pancakeswap and to test it I took already 4 of them and bought it. all of them I couldn't sell, not via code and also not manually. tried to set slippage to maximum (around 50% I think) played with it as much as I can. tried to sell 1 token, just half of them and even all of them none worked. some of the time we just receive an error said it is duo to low slippage or price changes and sometime we got an error said pancake k error.

this is a failed selling transaction we tried to run via code f0x76ae5097e46c7004ed552111f6aad8210e9406a49b8df4688aa3e92d44415b20
link for the transaction: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x76ae5097e46c7004ed552111f6aad8210e9406a49b8df4688aa3e92d44415b20

also looked in tenderly: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc/0x76ae5097e46c7004ed552111f6aad8210e9406a49b8df4688aa3e92d44415b20/debugger?trace=0.2
and it seems like this is failing on the swap function. this has made me think that the guys that open those coins are making it impossible to sell them in order to scam people and after they get enough money the close liquidity and move on to the next scam. but I couldn't find in their contract anything that looked odd to me. I have experience in code and I am working as a software engineer at Microsoft though I have none experience in solidity so if anyone can help me understand if that is indeed a scam and where can you see it in the code and validate that this make it impossible to sell. this is the contract of the coin in the example above:
coin token: 0x3F72126d4D344f50A006CEF571d2fA5BAb74617b
https://bscscan.com/address/0x3F72126d4D344f50A006CEF571d2fA5BAb74617b

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not buy random tokens or you get shit like this.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the error happened because you’re trying to buy or sell tokens at a large price movement. Due to the issue, some users will think that the token that they’ve bought is a scam. The token is only a scam if you’re encountering the `TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED`  error. To fix the “Pancake K” error on PancakeSwap, you need to change amount of tokens that you’re trying to swap. Alternatively, you can try increasing your slippage tolerance up to 12%.

Link: [How to Fix “Pancake K” Error on PancakeSwap](https://www.followchain.org/pancake-k-pancakeswap/)